# update parameter in while loop D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, while-loop, slider, interactive

I was hoping somebody could help, I'm completely new to javascript but have been learning it in order to start producing interactive outputs in D3.

So I've started with the basics and produced line graphs etc, now I want to add an interactive element.

So I have a line graph, a slider and a function, the question is how do I link these up? playing with some online examples I understand how I can get the slider to update attributes of objects such as text, but I want it to update parameters in a loop to perform a calculation, which then runs and gives the line graph output.

My code is as follows and I've annotated the loop which I want to update:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
        path {
            stroke-width: 2;
            fill: none;
        }

        line {
            stroke: black;
        }

        text {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 9pt;
        }

    </style>
<body>

 <p>
  <label for="repRate" 
         style="display: inline-block; width: 240px; text-align: right">
         R = <span id="repRate-value">…</span>
  </label>
  <input type="range" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.01" id="repRate">
</p>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>


d3.select("#repRate").on("input", function() {
  update(+this.value);
});


update(0.1);


function update(repRate) {

  // adjust slider text
  d3.select("#repRate-value").text(repRate);
  d3.select("#repRate").property("value", repRate);

}


//This is the function I want to update when the slider moves, I want the parameter R to update
//with the slider value, then loop through and produce a new graph
function parHost (R){
var i = 0;
var result = [];
      do {
      //I want to be able to keep it as a loop or similar, so that I can add more complex
      //equations into it, but for now I've kept it simple
        Nt1 = R*i
        result.push(Nt1++) ;
        Nt = Nt1
        i++;
      }
      while (i < 50);
        return result};



      var data = parHost(0.5),
            w = 900,
            h = 200,
            marginY = 50,
            marginX = 20,
            y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0 + marginX, h - marginX]),
            x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0 + marginY, w - marginY])


            var vis = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)

            var g = vis.append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0, 200)");

            var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
                .y(function(d) { return -1 * y(d); })

            g.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data)).attr('stroke', 'blue');

            g.append("svg:line")
                .attr("x1", x(0))
                .attr("y1", -1 * y(0))
                .attr("x2", x(w))
                .attr("y2", -1 * y(0))

            g.append("svg:line")
                .attr("x1", x(0))
                .attr("y1", -1 * y(0))
                .attr("x2", x(0))
                .attr("y2", -1 * y(d3.max(data)))


            g.selectAll(".xLabel")
                .data(x.ticks(5))
                .enter().append("svg:text")
                .attr("class", "xLabel")
                .text(String)
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) })
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

            g.selectAll(".yLabel")
                .data(y.ticks(4))
                .enter().append("svg:text")
                .attr("class", "yLabel")
                .text(String)
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", function(d) { return -1 * y(d) })
                .attr("text-anchor", "right")
                .attr("dy", 4)

            g.selectAll(".xTicks")
                .data(x.ticks(5))
                .enter().append("svg:line")
                .attr("class", "xTicks")
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d); })
                .attr("y1", -1 * y(0))
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d); })
                .attr("y2", -1 * y(-0.3))

            g.selectAll(".yTicks")
                .data(y.ticks(4))
                .enter().append("svg:line")
                .attr("class", "yTicks")
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return -1 * y(d); })
                .attr("x1", x(-0.3))
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return -1 * y(d); })
                .attr("x2", x(0))





</script>
</body>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each slider input event you have to update the parts of the chart (e.g. `line`, `axisTicks`, etc.) which depend on your data. You could e.g. extend your update function like this:

```
function update(repRate) {
  // adjust slider text
  d3.select("#repRate-value").text(repRate);
  d3.select("#repRate").property("value", repRate);

  // Generate new Data depending on slider value
  var newData = parHost(repRate);

  // Update the chart
  drawChart(newData);
}
```

where the drawChart(newData) could look like this:

```
function drawChart(newData) {
  // Delete the old elements
  g.selectAll("*").remove();

  g.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(newData)).attr('stroke', 'blue');
  ...
}
```

Another method is to declare data depending elements as variables and just change their attribute on an update (which i would recommend):

```
...
var dataLine = g.append("svg:path");
...
function drawChart(newData) {
  path.attr("d", line(newData)).attr('stroke', 'blue');
}
```

Here is an example [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BiX6UswIDYLR1V8BXpDo?p=preview).
Check out also this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8).